# Difference between Nested IF/ELSE and ELIF?

Tags: python, if-statement, structure

Is there any semantic or runtime difference between these two different code organizations? Or is it simply a matter of brevity and whitespace?

```
if something:
    ...
else:
    if other:
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Vs.

```
if something:
    ...
elif other:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no logical difference. Prefer the second way, using `elif`, it's more readable.

Note that at the abstract syntax level, they are exactly equivalent:

```
>>> s1 = """\
... if something:
...     ...
... else:
...     if other:
...         ...
...     else:
...         ..."""
...         
>>> s2 = """\
... if something:
...     ...
... elif other:
...     ...
... else:
...     ..."""
...     
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse(s1)) == ast.dump(ast.parse(s2))
True
```

Specifically, the `elif` form is transformed into the nested `if` form of flow control:

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse(s2))
"Module(body=[If(test=Name(id='something', ctx=Load()), body=[Expr(value=Ellipsis())], orelse=[If(test=Name(id='other', ctx=Load()), body=[Expr(value=Ellipsis())], orelse=[Expr(value=Ellipsis())])])])"
>>> # pip install astdump
>>> astdump.indented(s2)
Module
  If
    Name
      Load
    Expr
      Ellipsis
    If
      Name
        Load
      Expr
        Ellipsis
      Expr
        Ellipsis
```

Comment: Though the semantics are the same, I would be surprised if the equivalence of the ASTs was guaranteed by the language, and not the result of an implementation-specific optimization.

Answer (score 5):

Both are compiled to the same bytecode (in CPython at least):

```
>>> def a():
...     if something:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         if other:
...             return 2
...         else:
...             return 3
... 
>>> def b():
...     if something:
...         return 1
...     elif other:
...         return 2
...     else:
...         return 3
... 
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (something)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 RETURN_VALUE        

  5     >>   10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (other)
             13 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20

  6          16 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        

  8     >>   20 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             23 RETURN_VALUE        
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis(b)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (something)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       10

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              9 RETURN_VALUE        

  4     >>   10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (other)
             13 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20

  5          16 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
             19 RETURN_VALUE        

  7     >>   20 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             23 RETURN_VALUE        
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE
```

So the only difference is readability of the source. As others have said, the second variant is cleaner and should be preferred.

Comment: The bytecode is irrelevant here (and CPython implementation detail).  They are equivalent already after the parse/lex stage.

Comment: @wim So what? I'm just trying to show that the two ultimately produce the same result.

Comment: @wim As much as I think it's nitpicking, I added a note to the answer indicating that it does in fact pertain to CPython.

Answer (score -1):

Python is all about readability of code. You can find that in many more cases of python. Python follows the concept of "Less is Better".
If we talk about the question you have asked, there is no such difference in the two formats except redability.